# Neo4j - How to use createRelationshipIndex / createNodeIndex in full-text search

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

So I understand that Neo4j 3.5 and above implements full-text search in cypher query via `createNodeIndex()`, e.g.:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex("myIndex", ["PersonNode"], ["name"])
```

where `myIndex` is an arbitrary variable I make up to store the index, `PersonNode` is the name of my Node label, and `name` is one of the attributes of `PersonNode` where I want the full-text search performed.

And to actually perform the search by `name`, I can do something like the following:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("myIndex", "Charlie")
```

But now assume that `PersonNode` has a relationship of type `PURCHASED_ITEM`, which is connected to another node label `ProductNode` as follows:

```
PersonNode-[:PURCHASED_ITEM]->ProductNode
```

And assume further that `ProductNode` has an attribute called `productTitle` indicating the display title name for each product.

My question is, I would like to set up an index for this relationship (using, presumably, `createRelationshipIndex()`), and perform a full-text search by `productTitle` and return a list of all `PersonNode` that purchased the given product. How can I do this?

*Addendum: I understand that the above could be done by first getting a list of all `ProductNode` instances matching the given title, then performing a normal cypher query to extract all related `PersonNode` instances. I also understand that for the above example, a normal cypher query would be all that I need. But the reason I'm asking this question is that I eventually need to implement a single search bar that would allow the user to input any text, including possible misspellings and all, and have it perform a search through multiple attributes and/or relationships of `PersonNode`, and the results need to be sorted by some kind of relevance score. And in order to do this, I feel I need to first grasp exactly how the relationship queries work in neo4j.*

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to create a full-text index for the `productTitle` property of `PURCHASED_ITEM` relationships:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createRelationshipIndex("myRelIndex", ["PURCHASED_ITEM"], ["productTitle"])
```

And here is a snippet showing the use of that index:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships("myRelIndex", "Hula Hoop") YIELD relationship, score
...
```

Answer (score 0):

product title is the property of product node not the purchased item

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).